# Fix text mirroring on rear view of Object3D

Tags: android, canvas, opengl-es, android-bitmap, google-project-tango

My Class extends `Renderer(org.rajawali3d.renderer.Renderer)`

Following function in the class is called from activity :

```
public void makeText(float[] openGLPpoint, int color, String text,float depth) 
{
 double adjust_angle_o = 0;
 Material mSphereMaterial = new Material();
 Bitmap bitmap= setTextInImage(text);
 Texture t = new Texture("text",bitmap);
 mSphereMaterial.addTexture(t);
 Object3D object3D = new Plane(0.3f,0.1f,100,100);
    object3D.setMaterial(mSphereMaterial);
    object3D.setDoubleSided(true);
    object3D.setColor(color);
    if(!depth >= 1)
    {   
        adjust_angle_o = 0.2;
    }
    object3D.setPosition(openGLPpoint[0],
            openGLPpoint[1],
            openGLPpoint[2]-adjust_angle_o);
    getCurrentScene().addChild(object3D);
}


public Bitmap setTextInImage(String text){
    Bitmap src =
            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),R.drawable.label_bg_sm);
    Bitmap dest =
            Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(),
                    src.getHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas cs = new Canvas(dest);
    Paint tPaint = new Paint();
    tPaint.setTextSize(50 * mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    tPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    tPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    tPaint.setFakeBoldText(true);
    cs.drawBitmap(src, 0f, 0f, null);
    float height = tPaint.measureText("yY");
    float width_o = tPaint.measureText(text+" m");
    float x_coord = (src.getWidth() - width_o)/2;

    // 15f is to put space between top edge and the text

    cs.drawText(text+" m", x_coord, height+15f, tPaint);
    return dest;
}
```

I need the factor `object3D.setDoubleSided(true);` , which is working fine .

The text is correct when seen from front view but when the object is seen from the rear side , the text naturally mirrors .

Following is a snap :

[Mirrored text observed from rear view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSCN4.jpg)

How can the text be corrected , as it should be readable from both front and rear views ? Any articles to fix text-mirroring ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out , `object3D.setDoubleSided(false)` created a duplicate object and rotated it 180 at y axis . It worked fine now .

**Edit :** The rotated side is showing dark then the original . Increasing alpha isnt working. Can anyone guide futher ?